# wait system call doesnot returning proper child status

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, wait, suse

Write now I am migrating some piece of code from AIX to SUSE Linux. In AiX we have below code worked properly:

```
int Wait_for_child()
{
    alarm(10);
    while (((p_id = wait(&return_code)) > 0) ||(child_signal == 1)) {
       alarm(0);
     .......Do Something
    }
 return TRUE;
}
```

We are killing the child by passing a SIGINT from another function and we are killing it successfully.

```
if ((status = kill(proc_info->process_id, SIGINT)) != 0) 
{
    log.printf("fail");      
    return(FAIL)
 }
```

but in LINUX the wait system call does not return child process id which gets terminated recently.
Please share your ideas.
Thanks

Comment: debugging ideas: `strace -p` the parent process to find out what it does when the child dies... check the child process with `ps` to see if it's a zombie

Comment: what do you get as return value of wait() ?

Comment: wait is returning -1 every time

Comment: Are you handling `SIGCHLD`? is it set to `SIG_IGN`?

Comment: What is the value of errno when -1 is returned?  Change the call to waitpid and set the options param appropriately...  Do you have hung or what could look to the system like hung child processes? errno == EINTR can also screw up the code you posted.

Comment: yes ...we are handling SIGCHLD

Comment: it is returning ECHILD every time

Comment: Is there another thread calling wait?  [ECHILD] The calling process has no existing unwaited-for child processes.  Note that I remember AIX being kind of sloppy in this area when I was working with it around 2001 or so.  It, however, has been a long time and memory is hazy.